# Fullcalendar get coordinates while dragging (Goal: switch to next month when approaching side of the calendar)

Tags: javascript, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-5

I would like to implement in my calendar a feature that allows a user to switch to the next/previous month while dragging an event. My ideas was to check while the event is being dropped if the event is leaving the calendar to left/right to switch to the next/previous month.

I checked the docs and only found callbacks for the start and end of the dragging process but none that is being called while the event is being dragged.

I've tried binding the element that is being dragged to the  javascript drag event in the eventDragStart callback but that did not really work.

So, my question is how can I get the position of an event while it is being dragged?